# What files are required for mobileweb setup in Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, mobile-website, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on a cross device project in Appcelerator.  I have already defined the Android, iOS solutions and got all my icons and splash screens setup correctly.

I am struggling to understand what files I need for the favicon and the splash screens for mobile web.

I have a mobileweb folder under resources but I don't know what files I should be placing there and what resolutions they should be.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile web behaves differently than iOS and Android regarding the splash screen. You do not need a static image for it since its actually a web page.

In your folder (assuming your using Alloy here)

`app/assets/mobileweb/splash`

You need to have an html page titled `splash.html`. This is what mobile web uses to build your splash page. You can make this responsive and use embedded CSS or link to a CSS file etc for all your styles. Furthermore you can use JS and JS libs as needed.

To find out more about the requirements of MobileWeb splash and icons, you can check out our documentation here:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-MobileWebgraphicassetrequirementsandoptions

Comment: One other comment, keep in mind that HTML5 with Titanium really is meant for MobileWeb and not desktop web (although it has been used for the latter). This is why the recommended sizes etc referenced in the documentation are more suited for mobile device sizes than desktop.

Comment: Actually I dont use alloy.  I am a long time user of appcelerator and write using native javascript.  What I am not clear on is how i can define the index.html customisations including the favicon and add festures thst will slow the page to work offline.

Comment: I saw this document but it does not make what i need.  For example i want to provide a favicon but i dont know where to put it and what to call it.  I tried renaming it appicon.png placing it in the mobileweb folder in resources nut this did not work (neither did placing a favicon file there.